# Adding field title when viewing profile Wordpress Frontend

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have tried to find the answer to this one but Have struggled Running Civi 5.65.2 on WP 6.3.1

I am setting up a member area of  the site and I want people to be able to view in the front end the details we have registered for them and if they are incorrect I want them to be able to edit them.  I have set up a profile  and have two pages one with [civicrm component="profile" gid="26" mode="view" hijack="0"] and one with [civicrm component="profile" gid="26" mode="edit" hijack="0"].

When they are in the edit view they can see what all the field names are [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfX5.png), but when in view mode they can't [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwFk8.png). How do I get it so they can see the field names in view mode as well?

Comment: Looks like the title or labels are hidden or color of the label text is white.

Comment: Yes thats hit the nail on the head! as just tried highlighting them and the titles Show up - do you know where the CSS code for the colour will be coming from here?

Comment: Its from your theme.. you can over-ride them on civi public pages